# FCM service unavailable nack

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, xmpp, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a python3 program that connects to the FCM XMPP test server successfully. However, after sending a JSON, it returns me a `SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` nack message every time. The very same piece of code worked perfectly last week.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref#error-codes) advises to retry to send the message, several times, what I did. It also says that I might be blacklisted.

- How can I know if I am blacklisted?
- What behavior can get you blacklisted? Is it possible to get blacklisted from the FCM **test** server?
- Is it a technical problem from FCM? It seems to [be working](https://status.firebase.google.com/).

The request that provokes the nack is:

```
<message id=""><gcm xmlns="google:mobile:data">{"message_id": "37ea7059-a832-413b-b008-378f8d8e1a46", "delivery_receipt_requested": true, "time_to_live": 600, "notification": {"body": "BAR", "color": "#666", "icon": "ic_launcher", "title": "FOO", "sound": "content://settings/system/notification_home"}, "data": {"url": "http://google.com"}, "to": "FOOBAR"}</gcm></message>
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue on the testing endpoint (port 5236) when sending messages targeted by registration token. Sending a message to a topic works. This issue is not happening when using the production endpoint (port 5235) [XMPP Ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/xmpp-server-ref)

Comment: Could you add the request that is resulting in the SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE nack?

Comment: @apidae Indeed, working with the production server seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Our Cloud Messaging staging environment regularly gets software releases that may not be fully ready for production use yet. It seems this is one of those cases.

We recommend that you do your own testing against the production environment. We'll update the documentation accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Is there a place we can see the test platform status? Also, can you answer my questions about blacklisting?